# XAML - Run code when WPF form closes

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a WPF form that is made up of UserControls and not Windows. Unlike Windows, UserControls don't have a `UserControl.Close` or a `UserControl.Closing`. I need to be able to run code when my application is closed out by clicking on the familiar red x at the upper right portion of the app. Has anyone ever done this? Keep in mind that I am using MVVM.

Here is the XAML for the page:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ClassName"
             <!--etc..-->
             >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!--Columns-->
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--Rows-->
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--WPF Content-->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usercontrol don't have close and closing events. therefore you can use unloaded but the unloaded not get fired autometicly

to dispose the usercontrols read the below article.

http://geekswithblogs.net/cskardon/archive/2008/06/23/dispose-of-a-wpf-usercontrol-ish.aspx

Comment: Good point about the unloaded event, realized it after i wrote my answer. Best bet is really the Dispatcher Shutdown or the application exit event.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any windows? How is that possible? Do you create them offscreen?

Well you can't make it completely in XAML obviously, but how about [Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.exit) if you want to be informed prior closing your application. If you want an interceptable and canceable solution you could use the [Closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing.aspx) on your main window, if you have one. Of course the [Closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closed.aspx) event is a solution aswell. And last but not least you got the [Unloaded event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.unloaded.aspx) on your user controls.

Hope that helps you a bit.

Comment: I'm using the Phoenix flavor of MVVM. No windows needed. You use a HomeControler to keep track of all your 'windows'. Inside the HomeController is a constructor for each 'window' which is called whenever you set a tile's `Commands:Invoke.OnClick` to `"Home.NameOfWindow"`. `Unload` is close to the only thing that will work. The problem is, is that when you exit the application using the red x, `Unload` never happens.

Comment: Well then there is only the application object, which is some sort of singleton, where you can listen for the Exit event.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out where the application listens for a close or exit. I tell ya, I am not a fan of MVVM.

Comment: Really? I love MVVM :) we use it through our whole application. But i agree, making it work for Windows and application can be a bit of a stretch. But i made a distinction between UI Models and Business Models. A Window or Application ViewModel exist but wraps the corresponding Window and Application UI Models. To create a new window all i need to do is to call ´ApplicationModel.Instance.Windows.Add(new CreateProjectWindowModel())´